# Connection string for iSeries on IBM.Data.DB2.Core

Tags: c#, ado.net, db2

We are trying to use the new IBM.Data.DB2.Core .net data provider and I'm running into an issue.

Our legacy code uses the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries package to query data on iSeries. We use the following connection string in the legacy code:

```
<add name="iSeries" connectionString="DataSource=server.company.com;LibraryList=LIBONE,LIBTWO,LIBTHREE;UserID=userID;Password=thepassword;" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" />
```

In order to use the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries data provider, the IBM client access drivers must be installed on the server.  The new IBM.Data.DB2.Core .NET data provider can be used without having the client access drivers installed on the server which is a big plus.  There are examples of using the IBM.Data.DB2.Core .net data provider at the following url:
[Getting started with IBM Data Server provider for EntityFramework Core using Visual Studio 2015 update 3](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Getting_started_with_IBM_EntityFramework_Core_using_Visual_Studio_2015?lang=en)

In the example, they have the following code:

```
optionsBuilder.UseDb2(@"Server=<servername>:<portno>;Database=<dbname>;userid=<uid>;password=<pwd>", p=>p.SetServerInfo( <Platform Type>, <Server Version> ));
```

Notice the connection string doesn't have a LibraryList property, only a Database property.  If I try to add a library list, there is an error.  If I try to use one of the  libraries from the legacy connection string as the value for the Database property, there is an error.

What would be the equivalent connection string for this new .net core driver?

Comment: Hi, Did you fix the issue? I have the same issue and I do not know how to build a correct connection string for IBM db2 core.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Ever get a resolution?

Comment: The same here, need help!

Answer (score -1):

I use this connection string :

```
Server=servername:port; Database=databasename; UID=username; PWD=password
```

With :

> IBM.Data.DB2.Core - 1.3.0.100